# MYSQL RIGHT JOIN filters not working

Tags: mysql

This query is for pulling down comments and replies if you can imagine a comment thread. The problem is that I needed to include a right join to include comments(These have null column values in reply columns). The problem is that it is pulling down all of the comment rows as you can see from this picture. Why is my filters for pageId, classId, albumId not correctly filtering?

```
SELECT rp.votes, cmts.pageId, cmts.content_element_id, rp.userId as replyUserId, (select users.firstName from users where users.guid = rp.userId) as replyFirstName, 
(select users.lastName from users where users.guid = rp.userId) as replyLastName, rp.originalCommentId as replyOriginalCommentId,
rp.parentCommentId as replyParentCommentId, rp.commentId as replyCommentId, rp.text as replyText, rp.createdAt as replyCreatedAt,
rp.updatedAt as replyUpdatedAt, rp.status as replyStatus, cmts.classId as classId, cmts.albumId as albumId,
cmts.text as OriginalCommentText, cmts.status as CommentStatus, cmts.commentId as commentOriginalId,
cmts.createdAt as CommentCreatedAt, cmts.updatedAt as CommentUpdatedAt, cmts.status as cmtsStatus, cmts.userId as cmtsUserId, (select users.firstName from users where users.guid = cmts.userId) as commentFirstName, (select users.lastName from users where users.guid = cmts.userId) as commentLastName
FROM replies as rp
RIGHT JOIN comments as cmts ON rp.pageId = '36365094-0f52-49e3-bc0e-037edcca574b'
AND cmts.classId = '207'
AND cmts.albumId = '49152e6b-ca80-4889-a65e-4e6fd1dcc367'
AND rp.originalCommentId = cmts.commentId
ORDER BY cmts.createdAt
```

http://i59.tinypic.com/257q6wg.jpg

I cannot do an inner join, because it wont return the nulled values as seen from the picture.

@Gordon - I think I needed an extra and in there, like this: I'm double checking it now.

```
RIGHT JOIN comments cmts ON rp.pageId = '36365094-0f52-49e3-bc0e-037edcca574b' 
AND rp.originalCommentId = cmts.commentId
WHERE cmts.classId = '207' AND cmts.albumId = '49152e6b-ca80-4889-a65e-4e6fd1dcc367'  AND cmts.pageId = '36365094-0f52-49e3-bc0e-037edcca574b'
ORDER BY cmts.createdAt
```

Comment: because they are not filters. `RIGHT JOIN` will not filter any records, only provide matches or not. if you want them to be filters, use an `INNER JOIN`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are filtering on the second table in the `right join` in the `on` clause.  So, this does nothing.  Add a `where` clause:

```
where cmts.classId = '207'AND cmts.albumId = '49152e6b-ca80-4889-a65e-4e6fd1dcc367'
```

to do the filtering.

A `right join` keeps all the rows in the second table, regardless of whether the `on` clause evaluates to "true", "false", or `NULL`.  So, any filter on the second table is ignored.

(Note that for a `left join`, the same thing applies to the first table.)

EDIT:

The `from` clause would turn into:

```
FROM replies rp RIGHT JOIN
     comments cmts
     ON rp.pageId = '36365094-0f52-49e3-bc0e-037edcca574b' AND
        rp.originalCommentId = cmts.commentId
WHERE cmts.classId = '207' AND
      cmts.albumId = '49152e6b-ca80-4889-a65e-4e6fd1dcc367'
```

Comment: That pulls down 54 compared to the 71 that it was before, but I need the highlighted rows which are about 4 or 5

Comment: see the comment above. testing now.